# remove guid from file name shell script

Tags: shell, rename, batch-rename

I have a bunch of files in a directory that need to be renamed. These were created by the iPhone App for QNAP which uploads images and movie files from the phone to the NAS.

The file names are like so:

```
2014-02-21 20.50.29.MOV?id=BFE616C6-F951-4A51-9B33-084B73BF9341&ext=MOV
2014-02-22 12.31.58.JPG?id=7D2816AA-06D4-4F48-8908-23D327BB0A01&ext=JPG
```

These need to be renamed to the appropriate filenames. E.g.

```
2014-02-21 20.50.29.MOV?id=BFE616C6-F951-4A51-9B33-084B73BF9341&ext=MOV renamed to 2014-02-21 20.50.29.MOV
```

Windows doesn't allow me to do anything with these files, or I could have used something like [advancedrenamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com) to do the job.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

in bash you can use this:

```
rename 's/(.*)\?.*/$1/' *
```

Comment: unfortunately, i'm limited by what I can use on the QNAP. I don't have rename in the ipkg version of bash. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue.

```
for file in *.JPG\?id*;
    do mv "$file" "${file%%\?*}";
done
```

I basically did the same for each filetype, MOV, PNG, mp4 etc.